# Finding the direction of zero ascent of a mountain at a given point?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

The elevation on a mountain is 
$$z(x,y) = 10 − x^2 − 2y^2$$
$P : (1,1)$

What is the direction of zero ascent at the point $P$?

Comment: $z_x=z_y=0 $ should be satisfied..

Comment: Hint: if a function is differentiable at a point, then its directional derivative at that point vanishes in a direction that’s orthogonal to its gradient.